# Need to add a Regxp to Bulk Email Extractor. - excel VBA

Tags: excel, regex, vba, web-scraping, screen-scraping

**++++++++++++++ I have added new stuff at the bottom today, +++++++++++++++++**
**#############################################################################**
**+++++++++++ Edit today 7th Jan 2021 ########** **3:50PM UK TIME +++++++++++**
**#############################################################################**

**This is a few days old and I have abandonded it, unless someone can help, for new information please go to the bottom,**

I have been attempting to update my code to extract emails using a REGXP rather that Mailto: which it currently used. I posted on S.O a few months back asking for help, which I did receive and I am very grateful for. The new code was much longer than mine and more complicated for me to understand. I a very limited in VBA and was unable to make further changes to the new code. For the past few month I have been trying to update my existing code, with no luck.

As advised I am very limited in VBA, however I do understand my code and would like a MINOR change in it to enable me to extract emails via Regxp. **Please DO NOT re-write the whole code,** As this was done once and is out of my depth.

**This is My Original Code**

```
Sub ScrapeSoMeAndMailAddresses()
    'Columns for both tables
    Const colUrl As Long = 1                     'Must always be the first column
    Const colMail As Long = 2                    'Must always be the first column before Some platforms
    Const colFacebook As Long = 3                'Must always be the last column of Some platforms
    Const colError As Long = 4                   'Must always be the last column

    Dim url As String
    Dim http As Object
    Dim htmlDoc As Object
    Dim nodeAllLinks As Object
    Dim nodeOneLink As Object
    Dim pageLoadSuccessful As Boolean
    Dim tableUrlsOneAddressLeft As String
    Dim tableAllAddresses As String
    Dim currentRowTableUrls As Long
    Dim lastRowTableUrls As Long
    Dim currentRowsTableAll(colUrl To colFacebook) As Long
    Dim lastRowTableAll As Long
    Dim addressCounters(colMail To colFacebook) As Long
    Dim checkCounters As Long

    'Initialize variables
    tableUrlsOneAddressLeft = "Urls"             ''Name of Sheet
    currentRowTableUrls = 2                      'First row for content
    tableAllAddresses = "Results"                ''Name of Sheet
    
    For checkCounters = colUrl To colFacebook
        currentRowsTableAll(checkCounters) = 2   'First rows for content
    Next checkCounters
    
    Set htmlDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  
    'Clear all contents and comments in the URL source sheet from email column to error column
    With Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft)
        lastRowTableUrls = .Cells(Rows.Count, colUrl).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range(.Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail), .Cells(lastRowTableUrls, colError)).ClearContents
        .Range(.Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail), .Cells(lastRowTableUrls, colError)).ClearComments
    End With
  
    'Delete all rows except headline in the sheet with all addresses
    lastRowTableAll = Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(Rows.Count, colUrl).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Rows(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) & ":" & lastRowTableAll).Delete Shift:=xlUp
  
    'Loop over all URLs in column A in the URL source sheet
    Do While Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, 1).Value <> ""
        'Scroll for visual monitoring, if 'the sheet with the URLs are the
        'active one
        If ActiveSheet.Name = tableUrlsOneAddressLeft Then
            If currentRowTableUrls > 14 Then
                ActiveWindow.SmallScroll down:=1
            End If
            Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, 1).Select
        End If
    
        'Get next url from the URL source sheet
        url = Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colUrl).Value
    
        'Try to load page 'Temporarily disable error handling if 'there is a timeout or onother error
        On Error Resume Next
        http.Open "GET", url, False
        http.send
    
        'Check if page loading was successful
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            pageLoadSuccessful = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    
        If pageLoadSuccessful Then
            'Build html document for DOM operations
            htmlDoc.body.innerHtml = http.responseText
            'Create node list from all links of the page
            Set nodeAllLinks = htmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
            'Walk through all links of the node list
      
            For Each nodeOneLink In nodeAllLinks
        
                '''#####################################################################################################
                '''################################### THIS IS THE START OF THE EMAIL SECTION ##########################
                '''#####################################################################################################
                'Check for mail address
                If InStr(1, nodeOneLink.href, "mailto:") Then
                    'Write mail address to both tables
                    Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colMail).Value = Right(nodeOneLink.href, Len(nodeOneLink.href) - InStr(nodeOneLink.href, ":"))
                    Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colMail), colMail).Value = Right(nodeOneLink.href, Len(nodeOneLink.href) - InStr(nodeOneLink.href, ":"))
                    'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
                    If currentRowsTableAll(colMail) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
                        'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
                        Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
                        'Increment url counter
                        currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
                    End If
                    'Increment mail counters
                    currentRowsTableAll(colMail) = currentRowsTableAll(colMail) + 1
                    addressCounters(colMail) = addressCounters(colMail) + 1
                End If
    
                '''#####################################################################################################
                '''################################### END OF THE EMAIL SECTION ########################################
                '''#####################################################################################################

                'Check for Facebook address
                If InStr(1, UCase(nodeOneLink.href), "FACEBOOK") Then
                    'Write Facebook address to both tables
                    Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colFacebook).Value = nodeOneLink.href
                    Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook), colFacebook).Value = nodeOneLink.href
                    'Check if it is a new line in the sheet with all addresses
                    If currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook) >= currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) Then
                        'Write URL in the new line of the sheet with all addresses
                        Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(currentRowsTableAll(colUrl), colUrl).Value = url
                        'Increment url counter
                        currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) = currentRowsTableAll(colUrl) + 1
                    End If
                    'Increment Facebook counters
                    currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook) = currentRowsTableAll(colFacebook) + 1
                    addressCounters(colFacebook) = addressCounters(colFacebook) + 1

                End If

            Next nodeOneLink

            'Check address counters
            For checkCounters = colMail To colFacebook
                'Set comment if more than 1 link were found
                If addressCounters(checkCounters) > 1 Then
                    Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, checkCounters).AddComment Text:=CStr(addressCounters(checkCounters))
                    Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, checkCounters).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
                End If
            Next checkCounters
        Else
            'Page not loaded
            'Write message URL table
            Sheets(tableUrlsOneAddressLeft).Cells(currentRowTableUrls, colError).Value = "Error with URL or timeout"
        End If
    
        'Prepare for next page
        pageLoadSuccessful = False
        Erase addressCounters
        lastRowTableAll = Sheets(tableAllAddresses).Cells(Rows.Count, colUrl).End(xlUp).Row
        For checkCounters = colUrl To colFacebook
            currentRowsTableAll(checkCounters) = lastRowTableAll + 1 'First rows for next page content
        Next checkCounters
        currentRowTableUrls = currentRowTableUrls + 1
    Loop
  
    'Clean up
    Set http = Nothing
    Set htmlDoc = Nothing
    Set nodeAllLinks = Nothing
    Set nodeOneLink = Nothing

End Sub
```

**This is the Original Post on S.O with the new code that is out of my depth.**
[My Post on S.O](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685531/bulk-email-extractor-need-to-add-a-regxp-excel-vba)
In the above link there is the new code and a regxp in it, however I can not adapt this code to work with mine. If its RegXP function can be used and adapted with my code, then that would be super.

I have also tried to use this Regxp within my code, but with NO luck. In my above code I ONLY NEED THE EMAIL part updating  and NOT the whole code re-written.

```
For Each link In links
    'Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
      Set Html = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
With regxp
''' ########## Phone Numbers Pattern ###########
        .Pattern = "(?:\+1)?(?:\+[0-9])?\(?([0-9]{4})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{3}?)" '"(?:\+1)?(?:\+[0-9])?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{3}?)"
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        Set phone_list = .Execute(Html.body.innerHtml)
''' ########## Email Pattern ###########
        .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)"
        .Global = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
        Set email_list = .Execute(Html.body.innerHtml)
```

**'######## Edit today 6th Jan 2021 ########** **6:00PM UK TIME**

if I change this
`If InStr(1, nodeOneLink.href, "mailto:") Then`

To This
`If InStr(1, nodeOneLink.href, "@") Then`

Then I get slightly better results, Ideally I would like a regxp, if any one could help that would be super as I am stuck on this and can not go any futher

**##################################################################**

**'######## Edit today 6th Jan 2021 ########** **8:00PM UK TIME**
**###################################################################**

I was advised that this is the regxp that I need

```
Private Function GetEmailAddressesFromHtml(ByVal htmlDocument As Object) As Collection
    ' Should return a collection of strings representing email addresses detected
    ' in the HTML document.
   
    Dim outputCollection As Collection
    Set outputCollection = New Collection
   
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
   
    With regEx
        .Pattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+"
        .Global = True
        Dim emailMatches As Object
        Set emailMatches = .Execute(htmlDocument.body.innerHTML)
    End With
   
    Dim matchFound As Object
    For Each matchFound In emailMatches
        On Error Resume Next ' De-duplicate here.
        outputCollection.Add matchFound.Value, Key:=matchFound.Value
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next matchFound
   
    Set GetEmailAddressesFromHtml = outputCollection
End Function
```

And that it needs to go here

```
Dim colEmails as collection
Set colEmails = GetEmailAddressesFromHtml(htmlDoc)
If colEmails.Length >0 then 
*****ADD YOUR CODE HERE****
End If
```

However I have been trying for months now and can not work it out. If someone can advise that would be super.

**#############################################################################**
**+++++++++++++Edit today 7th Jan 2021 ########** **3:50PM UK TIME ++++++++++++**
**#############################################################################**

I have simplified the code, so now I have the regxp for emails and phones, however I can not workout the part on how to add the code to extract social media links.

**New Code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, links As Variant, link As Variant
Dim rw As Long
Dim regxp As New RegExp, post As Object, phone_list As Object, email_list As Object
Dim Html As New HTMLDocument

''''SHEET1 as sheet with URL
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
   
    rw = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    links = wsSheet.Range("A2:A" & rw)

For Each link In links
    'Set doc = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
      Set Html = NewHTMLDocument(CStr(link))
With regxp
''' ########## Phone Numbers Pattern ###########
        .Pattern = "(?:\+1)?(?:\+[0-9])?\(?([0-9]{4})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{4})[-. ]?([0-9]{3}?)" '"(?:\+1)?(?:\+[0-9])?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{3}?)"
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        Set phone_list = .Execute(Html.body.innerHtml)
''' ########## Email Pattern ###########
        .Pattern = "([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)"
        .Global = False
       .IgnoreCase = True
        Set email_list = .Execute(Html.body.innerHtml)
    

'''########## PHONE LIST ############# ADD TO SHEET
On Error Resume Next
    If phone_list(0) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = "-"
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
            Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "B").Value = phone_list(0)
    End If
'''########## EMAIL LIST ############# ADD TO SHEET
On Error Resume Next
      If email_list(0) Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
            Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "C").Value = "-"
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
            Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1, "C").Value = email_list(0)
    End If
End With
''''navigate links
     Next link

End Sub

Public Function NewHTMLDocument(strURL As String) As Object
    Dim objHTTP As Object, objHTML As Object, strTemp As String
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.send
    If objHTTP.Status = 200 Then
        strTemp = objHTTP.responseText
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    objHTML.body.innerHtml = strTemp
    Set NewHTMLDocument = objHTML
Else
   'There has been an error
End If
End Function
```

**I need something like this added to the above code**

```
Html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
                Set links = Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
'''COLUMN D = TWITTER
   For Each link In links
      If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "FACEBOOK") Then
      website.Offset(0, 3).Value = link.href
   End If
'''COLUMN E = TWITTER
    If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "TWITTER") Then
        website.Offset(0, 4).Value = link.href
    End If

Next
```

This is the Full Code from where the above code snip is from. I do not need all of what is below, only the part to extract social media links. I have also posed here [My Post On Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/need-help-to-write-this-vba-code-better.1157749/)

```
Dim counter As Long
Dim website As Range
Dim row As Long
Dim continue As Boolean
Dim respHead As String

''''The row where website addresses start
row = 2
    continue = True

Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    Do While continue
'''Could set this to first cell with URL then OFFSET columns to get next web site
Set website = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & row)
        If Len(website.Value) < 1 Then
            continue = False
        Exit Sub
        End If

        If website Is Nothing Then
            continue = False
        End If

'''Debug.Print website
    With http
        On Error Resume Next
        .Open "GET", website.Value, False
        .send

'''If the website sent a valid response to our request, URLS ARE IN COLUMN A
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If .Status = 200 Then
            Html.body.innerHTML = http.responseText
                Set links = Html.getElementsByTagName("a")
'''COLUMN D = TWITTER
   For Each link In links
      If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "FACEBOOK") Then
      website.Offset(0, 3).Value = link.href
   End If
'''COLUMN E = TWITTER
    If InStr(UCase(link.outerHTML), "TWITTER") Then
        website.Offset(0, 4).Value = link.href
    End If

Next
    End If
    Set website = Nothing
Else
'''Debug.Print "Error loading page IN COLUMN H"
    website.Offset(0, 8).Value = "Error with website address"
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
 End With
row = row + 1
Loop

Complete.Show '#### THIS FORM DOES NOT SHOW AT THE END ####
''' CLOSE BROWSER
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
Set ElementCol = Nothing
```

Comment: What isn't working with your email attempt? Also, to be [mcve] you could just reduce this to the email extraction code. It would help you and us to focus on the actual problem.

Comment: Your second code block needs indenting properly. I don't know if it is a copy paste error or your actual code.

Comment: Currently it uses Mailto:, The problem is the Mailto: does not extract enough emails, with a regxp I can extract more. I already have a regxp email ONLY code, However this code uses a table process and therefore can extract as many emails on the site. Where as my Email only code only extracts 1 code per site. If you click on the url link to  my original post, within that post there is another link to me email/phone number extraction code.

Comment: Hiya, 1) Re `MailTo`: From what I can understand from a quick scan of the above, you should really look into querySelectorAll and css attribute selectors as you want to filter href attributes from a page based on substrings they contain. I know you don't want a re-write but have a think about it as it would reduce your code complexity. 2) Re `the actual question` (I think) i.e. the regex for emails: The tel number stuff is irrelevant here and you haven't explained what isn't working with your email regex.

Comment: If it is a regex question you can probably then tag as such and provide suitable example inputs and expected outputs. I know I have made a lot of comments hopefully some help.

Comment: All I am trying to do is replace the block of code for mailto with a regxp as the regxp extracts more emails that the mailto. In my above code I have highlight the the start and end of the email code, that is the only part that needs changing as it does not pull of enough results. I would like it replaced with a regxp. I do not want the whole code changed or rewritten on the mailto part